# How to debug unittests with pudb debugger?

Tags: python, python-unittest, pudb

I am having some trouble trying to debug some unit tests through the [pudb debugger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).

The tests run fine with python, but I had no luck runnign them with `pudb`.

I isolated the problem, getting to the following sample code:

```
class Math:
    def pow(self, x, y):
        return x ** y

import unittest

class MathTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testPow23(self):
        self.assertEquals(8, Math().pow(2, 3))
    def testPow24(self):
        self.assertEquals(16, Math().pow(2, 4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The tests run fine:

```
$ python amodule.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

But if running through pudb, it gives me the output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I've tried running using `pudb amodule.py` and also with `python -m pudb.run amodule.py`, but it makes no difference -- no tests are run in one or another way.

Should I be doing something different to debug unit tests using pudb?

Comment: @LukasGraf Nice, that did it, thank you! Please, post this as an answer so I can give you credit. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try placing a breakpoint on a useful line in your code:

```
from pudb import set_trace; set_trace()
```

The ways you tried to launch it might interfere with test discovery and/or not run your script with a  `__name__` of `'__main__'`.

Comment: And what about the postmorten debug ? I did use to call the program like `pudb myprogram params` and it stops in the first error. Can we do the same with `pudb` and `unittests` ? I mean stop at the first error and get the postmorten debug ?

Comment: @yucer that will depend of your test runner. In case you use pytest, you can install this plugin https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pudb/ and then run `pytest --pudb`

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a popular question, I feel I should also mention that most test running tools will require you to pass in a switch to prevent it from capturing the standard output and input (usually it's `-s`).

So, remember to run `pytest -s` when using Pytest, or `nosetests -s` for Nose, `python manage.py test -s` for Django tests, or check the documentation for your test running tool.

Comment: the question is about unittest not pytest

Comment: @GM I think I know that, it was me who asked the question. Read again my answer, it's not specific to pytest.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you asked the question, I didn't find an answer to your question in your answer :-). So I have upvoted your question but downvoted your answer which is more comment in my opinion.

Comment: My question was "how to debug unit tests with pudb", my answer is right on topic. Question for you: do you believe my answer is not useful? Because clearly at least two other people found it useful, probably because they had the same problem I had, which made me come back to add this answer years after i had originally wrote the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a breakpoint even easier by:

`import pudb; pu.db`